# How do I copy a color from one project to another in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, palette, eyedropper

I have a project that has a color.  I want to use that color in a different project.

**How do I copy a color from one project to another?**

From what I've looked up, it seems like one has to do something that involves creating, managing, and importing custom color palettes between multiple projects.  This seems way over the top for something so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **copy** an object from one Illustrator document and **paste** it into another document.

- If the color was a **swatch** in the original document, a new swatch will be created for the color when you paste.
- If the color was *not* a swatch in the original document, click the "New Swatch" icon at the bottom of the **Swatch Panel** to create a swatch of the color.

Hit <kbd>DEL</kbd> to delete the pasted object.

This *reads* as more complicated than it really is... if you utilize swatches, it's really a half second...

- Copy <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
- Switch window <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>
- Paste <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
- Delete <kbd>Del</kbd>

---

It is also possible to **load** the swatches in any AI document into a **Swatch Panel** so the swatches are accessible without the actual original .ai file being open.

From the **Swatch Panel Menu** choose `Open Swatch Library... > Other Library...` navigate to *any* .ai file and select it. All swatches in the selected document will be loaded as a floating swatch panel.

Comment: Thanks for the details.  It turns out that the original document does not have swatches, so it's the somewhat more circuitous route of creating a "New Swatch" each time.

Comment: @LibrarySeph You can make them swatches... Select all and hit the Color Group Icon at the bottom of the Swatch Panel. It'll create swatches for all non-gradient, non-pattern colors.

Comment: @LibrarySeph realistically any color that you intend to be key component in your design should be a swatch. Maybe even a global swatch as it makes you more organized.

Comment: @joojaa I appreciate the concept for professional work.  From an introductory teaching role... less so.

Comment: @LibrarySeph whats so hard conceptually about writing down the colors you used. For introduction you should definitely teach the concept.